# Web scraping data from Transfermarkt

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I wrote a web-scraping procedure to scrape data from Transfermarkt.de

First, I get the data from the 20 biggest transfer from the last 10 years

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 
           'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'}

df_consolidado = pd.DataFrame()
df = {}
temporadas = list(range(2009,2020))

#Crio os lista para armazenar as informações
Jogadores = []
Valores_Transf = []
Href = []

for t in temporadas:
    print(t)
    for p in range(1,5):
        #Carrega a pagina p do temporada t
        page = "https://www.transfermarkt.de/transfers/transferrekorde/statistik/top/saison_id/" + str(t) + "/land_id//ausrichtung//spielerposition_id//altersklasse/u23/leihe//w_s//plus/0/galerie/0/page/" + str(p)        
        print(page)
        pageTree = requests.get(page, headers=headers)
        pageSoup = BeautifulSoup(pageTree.content, 'html.parser')

        #Pega os dados das transferências
        jogador = pageSoup.find_all("a", {"class": "spielprofil_tooltip"})        
        valor_transf = pageSoup.find_all("td", {"class": "rechts hauptlink"})

        #Introduzo as informações nas listas
        for i in range(0,25):
            Jogadores.append(jogador[i].text)
            Valores_Transf.append(float(valor_transf[i].text.replace('Mio.', '').replace('€', '').replace(',', '.').replace('Leihgebühr:', '').replace('Leih-Ende', '0')))
            Href.append(jogador[i]['href'])

    df[t] = pd.DataFrame({"Temporada":int(t),"Jogador":Jogadores,"Valor Transferência":Valores_Transf, "Ref":Href})
```

Then I combine all those dfs:

```
#Combinar os vários dfs gerados
df = pd.concat([df[2009], df[2010],df[2011], df[2012], df[2013], df[2014],df[2015], df[2016], df[2017], df[2018], df[2019]])
```

But at the last and most important step, I'm finding some troubles. Through the following code, I tried to get more detailed info:

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 
           'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'}

Altura = []
Idade_Atual = []
Idade_Transf = []
Maior_Valor = []
Data_Max_Valor = []


for index, row in df.iterrows():
    page = "https://www.transfermarkt.de" + row['Ref']
    pageTree = requests.get(page, headers=headers, timeout=1000)    
    pageSoup = BeautifulSoup(pageTree.content, 'html.parser')

    #Carrego o objeto contendo os dados
    dados_agrupados = None
    dados_agrupados = pageSoup.find_all("table", {"class": "auflistung"})
    
    dados = []
    tabela = []
    print(page)
    for d in dados_agrupados:
        dados.extend(d.find_all("td"))
        tabela.extend(d.find_all("th"))

        #Verifico a estrutura da table para copiar os dados
        for t in range(len(tabela)):            
            if tabela[t].text == "Height:":                
                if dados[t].text != "N/A":
                    Altura.append(float(dados[t].text.rstrip(' m').replace(',', '.')))
                else:
                    Altura.append(0)
                
            if tabela[t].text == "Age:":
                Idade_Atual.append(int(dados[t].text))
                Idade_Transf.append(int((row['Temporada']-2020) + int(dados[t].text)))
            
            if tabela[t].text == "Foot:":
                Pe_Dominante.append(dados[t].text)
                
    
    #Carrego o objeto contendo o maior valor de mercado do jogador
    dados_agrupados_val = None
    dados_agrupados_val = pageSoup.find_all("div", {"class": "right-td"})    

    Data_Max_Valor.append(int(dados_agrupados_val[2].text.replace(' ', '')[-5:-1]))
    if "k" in str(dados_agrupados_val[2].text.replace('Mio.', '').replace('€', '').replace(',', '.').replace(' ', '')[:-12]):
        Maior_Valor.append(float(dados_agrupados_val[2].text.replace('Mio.', '').replace('Â', '').replace('â', '').replace('¬', '').replace('k', '').replace('€', '').replace(',', '.').replace(' ', '')[:-12])/1000)
    else:
        Maior_Valor.append(float(dados_agrupados_val[2].text.replace('Mio.', '').replace('Â', '').replace('â', '').replace('¬', '').replace('€', '').replace(',', '.').replace(' ', '')[:-13]))
    
df["Altura"] = Altura
df["Idade_Atual"] = Idade_Atual
df["Idade_Transf"] = Idade_Transf           
df["Max_Valor"] = Maior_Valor
df["Data_Max_Valor"] = Data_Max_Valor

#Idade calculado quando o máximo valor de mercado foi atingido
df["Idade_Max_Valor"] = df["Data_Max_Valor"] - (df["Temporada"]-df["Idade_Transf"])

df
```

But I ended up with the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SysCallError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py in wrap_socket(self, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect, suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname)
    455             try:
--> 456                 cnx.do_handshake()
    457             except OpenSSL.SSL.WantReadError:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\SSL.py in do_handshake(self)
   1914         result = _lib.SSL_do_handshake(self._ssl)
-> 1915         self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)
   1916 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\SSL.py in _raise_ssl_error(self, ssl, result)
   1638                     if errno != 0:
-> 1639                         raise SysCallError(errno, errorcode.get(errno))
   1640                 raise SysCallError(-1, "Unexpected EOF")

SysCallError: (10054, 'WSAECONNRESET')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

SSLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    599                                                   body=body, headers=headers,
--> 600                                                   chunked=chunked)
    601 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    342         try:
--> 343             self._validate_conn(conn)
    344         except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError) as e:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in _validate_conn(self, conn)
    838         if not getattr(conn, 'sock', None):  # AppEngine might not have  `.sock`
--> 839             conn.connect()
    840 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py in connect(self)
    343             server_hostname=server_hostname,
--> 344             ssl_context=context)
    345 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py in ssl_wrap_socket(sock, keyfile, certfile, cert_reqs, ca_certs, server_hostname, ssl_version, ciphers, ssl_context, ca_cert_dir)
    346         if HAS_SNI and server_hostname is not None:
--> 347             return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
    348 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py in wrap_socket(self, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect, suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname)
    461             except OpenSSL.SSL.Error as e:
--> 462                 raise ssl.SSLError('bad handshake: %r' % e)
    463             break

SSLError: ("bad handshake: SysCallError(10054, 'WSAECONNRESET')",)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

MaxRetryError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    448                     retries=self.max_retries,
--> 449                     timeout=timeout
    450                 )

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    637             retries = retries.increment(method, url, error=e, _pool=self,
--> 638                                         _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
    639             retries.sleep()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py in increment(self, method, url, response, error, _pool, _stacktrace)
    398         if new_retry.is_exhausted():
--> 399             raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
    400 

MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.transfermarkt.de', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bojan-krkic/profil/spieler/44675 (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(10054, 'WSAECONNRESET')")))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

SSLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-7f98723c208e> in <module>
     11 for index, row in df.iterrows():
     12     page = "https://www.transfermarkt.de" + row['Ref']
---> 13     pageTree = requests.get(page, headers=headers, timeout=1000)
     14     pageSoup = BeautifulSoup(pageTree.content, 'html.parser')
     15 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py in get(url, params, **kwargs)
     73 
     74     kwargs.setdefault('allow_redirects', True)
---> 75     return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
     76 
     77 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py in request(method, url, **kwargs)
     58     # cases, and look like a memory leak in others.
     59     with sessions.Session() as session:
---> 60         return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
     61 
     62 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    531         }
    532         send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 533         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    534 
    535         return resp

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    644 
    645         # Send the request
--> 646         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    647 
    648         # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    512             if isinstance(e.reason, _SSLError):
    513                 # This branch is for urllib3 v1.22 and later.
--> 514                 raise SSLError(e, request=request)
    515 
    516             raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)

SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.transfermarkt.de', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bojan-krkic/profil/spieler/44675 (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(10054, 'WSAECONNRESET')")))
```

Does anyone understand what's happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this might be a problem on the server side, not with your code. The `SysCallError` code you're getting is a Windows Sockets error code. Citing from the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/windows-sockets-error-codes-2):

> **WSAECONNRESET**
> 10054
>
> Connection reset by peer.
> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. This normally results if the peer application on the remote host is suddenly stopped, the host is rebooted, the host or remote network interface is disabled, or the remote host uses a hard close (see setsockopt for more information on the SO_LINGER option on the remote socket). This error may also result if a connection was broken due to keep-alive activity detecting a failure while one or more operations are in progress. Operations that were in progress fail with WSAENETRESET. Subsequent operations fail with WSAECONNRESET.

It might be that this was a temporary issue. I was able to run your script and send requests for quite a while without issues. If this keeps happening when sending requests to that server, consider catching these exceptions using something like this:

```py
try:
    pageTree = requests.get(page, headers=headers, timeout=1000)
except requests.exceptions.SSLError as e:
    print(f'request to {page} failed: {e}')
    # or retry the request until it succeeds
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be because if the pyOpenSSL version you use, try updating it with the help of this [link](https://www.pyopenssl.org/en/stable/install.html).